# Azure SQL database backup to local server in weekly automatically

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, database-backups

I'm trying to configure azure sql database backup to my local server in weekly basis. This backup will be automatically. even its fine its possible togenerate database script through c# code. There have any tools or c# code that I can create schedule task to take back  in weekly or daily interval ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Azure feature for the automated backups.

If you setup using the azure webapp, be aware that you can find the backups option at the server (and not at the database) level.

For the retention policies and the frequencies you can look into the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?tabs=single-database) which is well written.

Answer (score 2):

OK, while the ans by @Giovanni Patruno is totally correct, I will share a **no-cost** and p**latform-independent** solution, that I am using to backup my DBs.

**By No-cost I mean**, Azure automated backups and retention policies have cost associated with it but if you want to save that bit, you can design your custom backup pipeline using SQLPackage.exe or PowerShell Az module.

**By Platform independent I mean**, by using Azure automated backups you can only backup your database on Azure servers. What If you want to restore it in your local environment be it windows or Linux? Then you go the following way:

1. Create .BACPAC file of your Azure SQL database using SQLPackage.exe at the scheduled time and either download and store it locally or store it in Azure storage account. Later you can restore your database on windows or Linux using SQLPackage.exe (!again) or keep this file for as long as you want for LONG TERM RETENTION.
2. You can do the above processes using PowerShell AZ module as well.

Both of these processes are well documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export).